# Why simple state+effect combination in root component crashes my entire app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is code of my root component, it is named 'app.jsx' by default.
When I'm trying to use some states and effects here, it crashes states on nested components.
Without this state and effect all works just fine, also I tried setting state on nested components - no errors.

```
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import StepInfo from './StepInfo';

export const StepContext = createContext(null);
export const StepSetterContext = createContext(null);

export default function App() {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
    
    // my state and effect that produce errors
    // errors happen with all other state & effect formats

    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(
        window.matchMedia("(max-width: 850px)")
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        window.matchMedia("(max-width: 850px)")
        .addEventListener('change', 
        (e) => setIsMobile(e.matches);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <main className='main'>

            // providing contexts to child components
            <StepContext.Provider value={step}>
                <StepSetterContext.Provider value={setStep}>

                   // child components with states
                    <StepInfo />
                    <Form />

                </StepSetterContext.Provider>
            </StepContext.Provider>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Can u please tell me, what kind of problem can be here?
p. s. this is my first project with React.

I've tried simply delete this state - since that moment all start working fine, then I'm again use it - it crashes.

p.s. Format of all errors: "nameOfState" is null or "state setter function is null"

Comment: What is the error message? Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codesandbox.io or similar if you need a node-like online environment.

Comment: Updated my post on error message format.